# How to list printer names acceptable for use with lpr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, printing, lpr

The `lpr` man page says a destination printer can be specified with the `-P` flag.

> ```
> -P destination[/instance]
>     Prints files to the named printer.
> ```

I have 'added' various printers on local Samba shares using the GUI in Ubuntu/Gnome. How can I get a list of these available printers in the format that the `-P` flag expects (preferably from a bash shell)?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
$ lpstat -p -d
```

From the [CUPS manual](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html#PRINTER).

> The `-p` option specifies that you want to see a list of printers, and the `-d` option reports the current default printer or class.

Comment: Thank you! I've just found that `lpq` works too.

Comment: Whenever I'm looking for this, I'm also looking for how to pick a default printer: `lpoptions -d printername`

Comment: I wanted to know the list of available printers because (shortened): "lpr: Error: default destination does not exist.". 
So now "lpr -p" and... same error message.

Answer (score 21):

## To get a list you can use:

```
lpstat -a
```

or

```
cat /etc/printcap
```

## To print only the printer names:

**lpstat + read + array:**

```
$ while read l; do l=($l); echo "${l[0]}"; done <<< "$(lpstat -a)"
```

**lpstat + awk:**

```
$ lpstat -a | awk '{print $1}'
```

**lpstat + cut:**

```
$ lpstat -a | cut -f1 -d ' '
```

**cat + grep + cut in `/etc/printcap`:**

```
$ cat /etc/printcap | cut -f1 -d'|' | grep '^#' -v
```

**This is what is shown, one per line:**

```
HP_LaserJet_P1606dn
HP_Deskjet_2540_series
HP_LaserJet_M1212nf
GCP-Save_to_Google_Docs
```

I feel like the `lpstat` solutions are more elegant and reliable. Mostly because `/etc/printcap` was not found on some systems I tested.

About using `awk` or `cut`, depends on what you have installed and prefer. The bash read + bash array option should work on any bash shell without the need for externals.

**EDIT :** I said the marked solution does no work for me on Amazon Linux. But I guess it works if you just want to copy the printer names from the middle of the rest of the output. Works the same as using just `lpstat -a`.

```
$ lpstat -p -d
printer HP_Deskjet_2540_series is idle. enabled since Tue 22 Dec 2015 01:12:10 PM BRST
. . .
printer GCP-Save_to_Google_Docs is idle. enabled since Tue 15 Dec 2015 02:13:33 AM BRST
system default destination: HP_LaserJet_P1606dn
```

Comment: lpstat + cut will work on OS X as well.

Comment: According to your output sample, `lpstat -p -d` seems to work…

Comment: Sorry, but he asks `How can I get a list of these available printers in the format that the (lpr) -P flag expects`. My example of `lpstat -p -d` clearly shows that you get more than just the printer name with that. On which case you cannot use that output for a `lpr -P $PRINTERNAME` call. So, no! `lpstat -p -d` does not work in the example I gave.